# ios keyboard clickable but not visible

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I'm making an app that allows users to ask questions. In my addQuestion class I have a UITextView where users write out their questions.

My issue is that occasionally on my iPhone the keyboard will not be visible (this does not happen every time—only the first time I open the app—sometime it even works right away). The strange part is that I can still press on the keys of the keyboard and type a response based on where the keys should be if the keyboard were visible. The issue is simply with visibility (and I tried moving the UITextView so that it wouldn't block the keyboard). After about 20 or 25 seconds the keyboard shows up.

I also used apple's recommended way of troubleshooting:

```
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        NSLog(@"isKeyWindow = %d window level = %.1f frame = %@ class = %@\n",
              window.isKeyWindow, window.windowLevel,
              NSStringFromCGRect(window.frame), window.class.description);
    }
```

but there is not a custom window covering the UITextEffectsWindow

It prints out:

```
isKeyWindow = 1 window level = 0.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UIWindow**

isKeyWindow = 0 window level = 10.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UITextEffectsWindow**
```

When it finally works  and the keyboard is visible:

```
isKeyWindow = 1 window level = 0.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UIWindow

isKeyWindow = 0 window level = 1.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UITextEffectsWindow
```

Maybe it has something to do with the window level being 10.0? When the keyboard eventually shows up the window level is 1.0...

Here is the .m class for more information

```
    @interface addQuestion () <UITextViewDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *questionText;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;

    @end

@implementation addQuestion

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.questionText becomeFirstResponder];
    self.questionText.delegate = self;
    self.questionText.text = @"Ask a good yes or no question!";
    self.questionText.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Post" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(posted)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;


//    for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
//        NSLog(@"isKeyWindow = %d window level = %.1f frame = %@ class = %@\n",
//              window.isKeyWindow, window.windowLevel,
//              NSStringFromCGRect(window.frame), window.class.description);
//    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Ask a good yes or no question!"] && [textView.textColor isEqual:[UIColor lightGrayColor]])[textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];

}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{

    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if (textView.text.length != 0 && [[textView.text substringFromIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"Ask a good yes or no question!"] && [textView.textColor isEqual:[UIColor lightGrayColor]]){
        textView.text = [textView.text substringToIndex:1];
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; //optional
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=YES;


    }
    else if(textView.text.length == 0){
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
        textView.text = @"Ask a good yes or no question!";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        textView.text = @"Ask a good yes or no question!";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; //optional
    }
    //[textView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
    if (text.length > 1 && [textView.text isEqualToString:@"Ask a good yes or no question!"]) {
        textView.text = @"";
        textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    if([[textView text] length] > 140){
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}  



@end
```

Comment: which device you used for testing ?

Comment: my iPhone 6 run through xcode

Comment: my real device that is... not the simulator

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava yes, just answered it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I tried to segue in a background thread (after a callback from NSURLSession).

What I should have done is made sure I called the segue in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"proceed" sender:self];
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.questionText becomeFirstResponder];
remove this
```

Comment: that only forced the user to manually press on the textview instead of automatically being able to type. It didn't make the keyboard visible. Thanks for the quick response though